# uniform distribution with interval (0,2) and sample 12

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

> Q): Suppose that you wish to sample $12$ observations randomly from a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,2)$. An approximate value of the probability that the average of your sample will be less than $0.5$.

what i did was i found the $\mathbb E(x)$ to be $1$ and variance to be $1/3$
and then i wasnt sure where to go with this so i decided to do the $z$-formula of 
$(0.5-1)/\sqrt{1/3}/\sqrt{12}$ to get me $z = -3$ then i got $p= 0.001350$ from that , i was just wondering if that was correct.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Your approximation to an answer is correct.

Comment: Simulation in R: `a = replicate(10^6, mean(runif(12, 0, 2)));
mean(a < .5)` returns 0.000979, accurate to about 3 places and agrees with $\approx 0.001$ from good normal approx.

Comment: @BruceET -but how many simulations would you need to distinguish between $0.001350$ and $0.001007$?

Comment: @Henry. I was just doing a 'reality check' on a tail probability so far out. With a million iterations it's $.001 \pm 0.0006.$ Maybe $10^7$ or $10^8$ would settle it, But the point is that the normal aprx should be good enough--even with an avg of only 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expectation of a single sample is $1$, with variance $\frac13$, so the average of twelve samples has an expectation of $1$ and variance of $\frac{1}{36}$, saying (as you found) that for this average $0.5$ would be $3$ standard deviations below the mean.  For a standard normal distribution, you are correct that the probability of values less than $3$ standard deviations below the mean is about $0.00135$

The difficult question is whether a normal approximation is a good approximation in this case: in particular normal approximations can sometimes perform relatively poorly in the tails

Your question actually involves a [Bates distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bates_distribution), but it is easier to handle translating it to the [Irwing-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution): you want the probability that the sum of $12$ uniform i.i.d. random variables on $[0,1]$ is less than $3$.  This is $$\frac{1}{12!}\left({12 \choose 0}(3-0)^{12} - {12 \choose 1}(3-1)^{12} + {12 \choose 2}(3-2)^{12}- {12 \choose 3}(3-3)^{12}\right) \approx 0.001007$$

So the exact answer is rather less than the normal approximation.  Whether the normal approximation is good enough, I leave for you to judge